# hyperledger fabric : access the private data only by the owner

Tags: javascript, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, ibm-blockchain

So I was trying hyperledger fabric private data collection feature, but since I'm a beginner, I don't know how to make that only the owner has access to his data and not the entire Organisation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way in fabric to do this. Collections Config only supports it at identity groups level

You will have to add necessary rules in your chaincode while querying and make your data aware of the ownerId

While storing the data
You can add a field to your data called OwnerId
stub.GetCreator() can be used to populate this field

While querying the data
In your chaincode, validate the OwnerId field with stub.GetCreator()